# read from pipe is blocking

Tags: linux, unix, ipc, pipe

I'm reading an unkown number of messages from a pipe. However, read is blocking. I've tried the below code to set the reads to non-blocking. However, this resulted in read errors and processes not reading all the way through.

```
// Set pipe to non-blocking
sleep(5);
fcntl(fd[index][0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

How can I successfully read and print all the messages, without the program hanging?
Here is the code that causes the issue:

```
// Read every message
while((n = read(fd[index][0], &mymsg, sizeof(int))) == sizeof(int))
    printf("process%d  has received a message from process%d\n", index, mymsg);
```

Comment: Read the documentation for select, poll, and epoll.

Comment: What errors do you get? A non-blocking socket will always return a "read error" when there was nothing to read.

Comment: @ZanLynx That is correct. When enough process are launched. The several of the processes will exit with a read error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use select() or epoll().  This is the standard way to achieve nonblocking reads (or writes) without multi-threading.

Comment: Can you give me an example for my case?

Comment: Read one of the hundreds of tutorials on select().